# Tkinter background image not showing up in new window

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have two issues here. I am just trying to learn tkinter. I want a background image on my second window. With the code below it doesn't display. Moreover, it says it can't read the file even if it's in the right place.

```py
class OrderWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Order Placement")
        self.minsize(1000, 625)
        self.maxsize(1000, 625)
        self.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        #self.configure(bg="#49a")
    
        self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="image5.jpg")
        self.pic = tk.Label(OrderWindow, image=background)
        self.pic.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`? Your second window should not be `Tk`, it should be `Toplevel`.

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage()` does not support JPEG image. Also should `tk.Label(OrderWindow, image=background)` be `tk.Label(self, image=self.background)` instead?

Answer (score -1):

> I want a background image on my second window.

The problem can be fixed.

- On line 7, Add `self.top = tk.Toplevel()`.
- On line 8, add the `title`, so we can see the second window `title`.
- On line 16, Typo error `tk.Label(OrderWindow, ....` should be `tk.Label(self.top....`
- On line 16, add `self` to `self.background`

Snippet modified:

```
import tkinter as tk

 
class OrderWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.top.title('Second window')
        self.title("Order Placement")
        self.minsize(1000, 625)
        self.maxsize(1000, 625)
        self.iconbitmap("class.ico")
        #self.configure(bg="#49a")
    
        self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
        self.pic = tk.Label(self.top, image=self.background)
        self.pic.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = OrderWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]